# Delete binary log on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have enabled binary log option on Google Cloud SQL. But seems `expire_log_days` option can not be configured on google developpers console.

Can I configure this option? If can't, when binary log will be deleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to configure expire_log_days

According to official doc: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/replication#binary-log-implication

> The storage of binary logs is charged at the same rate as regular data. Cloud SQL retains binary logs from the time when the oldest backup was taken (Cloud SQL currently retains 7 backups).

If you need to delete binary log manually, please contact cloud-sql@google.com